# I would like to handle an exception in case of re.match returns null

Tags: python, python-2.7

I've written this small piece of code:

```
import csv
import re
import os
fileobj = csv.reader(open('c:\\paths1.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in fileobj:
    for x in row:
        with open(x) as f:
            for line in f:
                if re.match('(.*)4.30.1(.*)', line):
                    print 'The version match: '+ line

                    print 'incorrect version'     
        filesize= os.path.getsize(x)


    print 'The file size is :'+ str(filesize) +' bytes';
```

What I would like to make it do is:

Add exception handling, as far as I know if the method `match()` doesn't
match anything in the file returns the value `None`, however I didn't quite understand 
how to read that value to make a comparison and let the script print (the version does not match)...

Anyone has any suggestion? It wouldn't be bad also to have some link to some web documentation.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're on the right way. As boolean value of `None` is False, all you have to do is use an `else` branch in your code:

```
 if re.match('(.*)4.30.1(.*)', line):
            print 'The version match: '+ line
 else:
            print 'incorrect version'
```

now i'm pretty sure you either want to match the first (the one that contains version number) line of the file or the whole file, so just in case:

```
      #first line
      with open(x) as f:
           try:
               #next(f) returns the first line of f, you have to handle the exception in case of empty file
               if re.match('(.*)4.30.1(.*)', next(f))):
                    print 'The version match: '+ line
               else:
                    print 'incorrect version'
           except StopIteration:
               print 'File %s is empty' % s


      #anything
      with open(x) as f:
           if re.match('(.*)4.30.1(.*)', f.read())):
                print 'The version match: '+ line
           else:
                print 'incorrect version'
```

Comment: thanks a lot!!!! I have also tried something like that however I didn't think it could be that straight-forward :) I love python(I used to program in turbo pascal)

Comment: -1. The OP wants to print "incorrect version" if NONE of the lines match. This code will print it once per non-matching line.

Comment: @JohnMachin yeah, he also says that `match` returns none when it doesn't match anything in the **file**, and then matches agains **lines**, so it's not at least not obvious what OP really wants.

Comment: @soulcheck: Do you really think he wants to print "incorrect version" for every non-matching line?

Comment: @soulcheck: or maybe the version can be on any line in the file (see my answer). Anyway, I've reversed the downvote.

Comment: @JohnMachim hard to tell really.

Comment: I used the first piece of code and it works, it print out wrong version when the ver does not mathc, thank you all!

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
import re #### don't need it
import os #### don't need it
fileobj = csv.reader(open('c:\\paths1.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
for row in fileobj:
    for x in row:
        with open(x) as f:
            for line in f:
                if '4.30.1' in line: #### much simpler than regex
                    print 'The version match: '+ line
                    break
            else: # Yes, a `for` statement can have an `else:` 
                # end of file, "break" doesn't arrive here
                print 'incorrect version' # done ONCE at end of file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> st = "hello stackers"
>>> pattern = "users"
>>> if re.match(pattern,st):
...      print "match found"
... else:
...     print "no match found"
...
no match found
>>>
```

Because `re.match()` returns `true` if match found.So,just use an `else statement` if `no` match is found.

Comment: -1. The OP wants to print "incorrect version" if NONE of the lines match. This code will print it once per non-matching line.